# How to import a stack if the VPCID for the InstanceSecurityGroup is String

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

```
MySecurityGroup: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties: 
      GroupDescription: Allow http to client host
      SecurityGroupIngress:
          - IpProtocol: tcp
            FromPort: 80
            ToPort: 80
            CidrIp: !Ref SSHLocation 
      SecurityGroupIngress:
          - IpProtocol: tcp
            FromPort: 443
            ToPort: 443
            CidrIp: !Ref SSHLocation
      SecurityGroupIngress:
          - IpProtocol: tcp
            FromPort: 22
            ToPort: 22
            CidrIp: !Ref SSHLocation
      VpcId: 
          - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${ExportVPCStack}-VPC
```

I'm getting an error that VPCId for Instance Security group is String.

How can i do this to avoid getting an error?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating `VpcId` as a list due to `-`. It should be:

```
      VpcId: 
         Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${ExportVPCStack}-VPC
```